# Figure caption aligns with center of page, but not with center of Figure

Tags: latex, figure, subfigure, figcaption, subcaption

[This is what it looks  like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfG23.png)

Hey People,

so I've been through every forum entry I could find about this, but I can't solve this Problem:
If I include multiple figures via subfigures, the centered captions hinder the figures from being side by side. I can't find a way to align my captions with the figures, rather than the page.

So far I've tried simply using two figures instead of one including subfigures. I've tried \captionsetup{width=0.33\linewidth,  justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false} but the caption wont budge.

```
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\small\itshape} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Abb.}}   
\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textbf{Tab.}}
```

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{img/Filter_Vorlage.JPG}}
        \captionsetup{width=0.33\linewidth, format=hang}
        \caption{Ausgangsbild vor Maximum}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{img/Filter_Max5x5.JPG}}
        \captionsetup{width=0.33\linewidth, format=hang}
        \caption{5x5 Maximum Filter angewendet}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill 
    \end{figure}
```

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\captionfont} {\small\itshape}    
\renewcommand{\figurename}  {\textbf{Abb.}} 
\renewcommand{\tablename}   {\textbf{Tab.}}


\title{StackOverflowExpl}
\author{me}
\date{September 2023}

\begin{document}

\section{FigureTest}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{img/Filter_Vorlage.JPG}}
        \captionsetup{width=0.33\linewidth, format=hang}
        \caption{Ausgangsbild vor Maximum}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{img/Filter_Max5x5.JPG}}
        \captionsetup{width=0.33\linewidth, format=hang}
        \caption{5x5 Maximum Filter angewendet}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill 
    \end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: @Robert : U got it. Problem hasn't changed on my side even using only this minimalistic code.

Comment: @Erdnuss Unrelated to your question, but you should not abuse `x` as multiplication symbol.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanks for your input. However the 'x' does not represent a multiplication, but indicates the size of a matrix that is used as a so-called 'kernel' in image analysis to process pixel values. Hence the 'x', not an asterisk.

Comment: It is a shorthand for `5 by 5`, thus you should use `\times` as multiplication symbol, not `x`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks got it. Is it appropriate to use $\times$ or is it recommended to always use mathmode?

Comment: You can use `5\texttimes 5`, then you don't need math mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the subfigure package for a subfigure is

```
\subfigure[⟨list entry⟩][⟨subcaption⟩]{⟨figure⟩}
```

This means while your code compiles more or less by accident, you aren't actually using any subcaption or anything other useful from it. So an easy solution to centre the normal caption with the image is using a `minipage` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\captionfont} {\small\itshape}    
\renewcommand{\figurename}  {\textbf{Abb.}} 
\renewcommand{\tablename}   {\textbf{Tab.}}


\title{StackOverflowExpl}
\author{me}
\date{September 2023}

\begin{document}

\section{FigureTest}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
            \captionsetup{width=\linewidth, format=hang}
            \caption{Ausgangsbild vor Maximum}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
            \captionsetup{width=\linewidth, format=hang}
            \caption{Ausgangsbild vor Maximum}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]